# Do something when one special field changes (doctrine)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, updates

I use symfony2 with doctrine. 
I want to do some changes when special attributes of an entity changes; actually I want to save the changes of my attributes and have an status of it's changes.
How can i say for example when any field changes do something relevant to the changed field's name.

for example if email changed, add some row to the other entity.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As addition to Yan answer, Doctrine already has methods for your needs like `hasChangedField`, `getNewValue`..
You can read more here:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate

Comment: as i read the documentation, it said that it's not usable if you want to make changes to entity associations.. and i want to add or remove another entity due to current entity's changes.. do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do something with Doctrine Listeners and UnitOfWork changeset, something like this :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class DoctrineListener
{
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        if ($entity instanceof MyEntityClass) {
            $changeSet = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
            if (isset($changeSet['my_field'])) {
                //do something here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example, this is how some of the Doctrine extensions are registering their changes.

Comment: thanks for your answer :), as i understand this will run before any update, is it right? so how is it's performance then?

Comment: Yes, the "preUpdate" Doctrine event is triggered when an entity is about to be updated (the entity exists, and some changes were applied to it before calling `persist`). I'm not sure to understand your question. "performance" ?

Comment: i mean how much is it's load on server? it's better to check attribute changes manually in your action or have this kind of listeners?

Comment: To me, this is not a matter of performance, but matter of code design. You can do everything on a controller, but think about code reusability. This is THE best practice of the Framework : thin controllers. And to answer your question, you can use event listeners, the component is optimized, and used by all Doctrine community! :)